# SSH: How to replace an empty passphrase with a non-empty passphrase in script

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

In script I need to add a passphrase to a pirvate key that has empty passphrase.

I have just tried this:

```
echo asdf | ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am PROGRAMMING a bash script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen) has a command-line option to specify the new passphrase (and the old one, if the key already has a passphrase):

> ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
>   [...]
>   **-p**
>   Requests changing the passphrase of a private key file instead of creating a new private key. The program will prompt for the file containing the private key, for the old passphrase, and twice for the new passphrase.
>
> **-P passphrase**
>   Provides the (old) passphrase.
>
> **-N new_passphrase**
>   Provides the new passphrase.